# How would I answer this? I recently started doing computer studies at school

Tags: computer-architecture

[image: a]
is this format okay? this is my first time using stackexchange.

Comment: The picture has poor quality and is therefore kind of hard to read.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 0):

You could just start at address `00`. The instruction that is stored there can be interpretet as load address `04`. Intrepreting the instruction at `01` you add the value stored at address `05` so the result is `9`. According to the instruction at address `02` this result gets sotred at address `06`.

So the program is basically adding the values sotred at addresses `04` and `05` and stores the result at address `06`.